# Running Eclipse and getting errors

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm attempting to create my first java program in Eclipse for the first time.

I created a Project--> Created a class

When I run the Class I get the following error output in the command window.

```
 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files
 (x86)\HP\LeanFT\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files  
 (x86)\HP\LeanFT\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
```

I went to the "starting up" documentation for Eclipse, but that doest not help either

What am I doing wrong?  Nothing I seem to look up online can help.

**Edit:**

Not sure if this is useful information but when I went to download the JDK I had to change the Path of the System Variable.

Comment: Not sure what this `\HP\LeanFT` path is doing... Did you create your project inside of Program Files?

Comment: Did you install the JDK?

Comment: Please show the value of the System Variable you set. Also show what you set the JDK settings in Eclipse.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I installed the JRE and had to change the Path of the System Variable

Comment: @cricket_007...

\HP\LeanFT is a Tool I'm trying to use as a plug in with Eclipse....

System Variable-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenel Shared\LNVSuite Client Components\7.1;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Card Scanning Solutions\SDK;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v.4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\LeanFT\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\\jre1.8.0_121\bin\

Comment: Is that the `PATH` variable? 1) You need to download the **JDK** 2) Try just setting a `JAVA_HOME` variable to the path of that JDK directory, and then you can use `%JAVA_HOME%` within the `PATH`

Comment: Also, that just looks like normal console output for Eclipse doing its thing... Where is the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by deleting Java_Options & Java_Tool_Options in the Environment Variables.

Answer (score 1):

Im using the Luna version for Windows and  the solution 
for the  red  eror "Picked up" is exactly to delete the _JAVA_OPTION in your Environment Variables  if you had aded it before. Its not a big problem to do not remove it because it will not prevent the  program to not work properly but you will still see the red sint after you play your program :)